# salt execute command on master

Tags: salt-stack

I have a .sls file to install Prometheus on minions, after it's done, I'd like to execute shell command on Salt master to add hostname of just provisioned minion to node_exporter.json file instead of manually editing this dynamic list of hosts to scrape. How can I achieve that? I need func similar to Ansible local_action.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have any details of the "shell command" or logic of updating minion details to `node_exporter.json` file. So I will directly come to this part:

> I need func similar to Ansible local_action.

In Saltstack there is no targeting mechanism from an SLS file. The `salt` and `salt-call` commands are the ones to use to target (like `ansible` ad-hoc command line).

So running the below command on Salt master...

```
salt-call --local test.ping
```

... would be similar to:

```
ansible localhost -m ping
```

So if you had an SLS file or shell command to update the `node_exporter.json` file, you could run it with `salt-call --local` on the Salt master. E.g.:

```
salt-call --local cmd.run <your shell command>
```